# Origin/Meaning of the title "The Blackcoat's Daughter"

Tags: title, the-blackcoats-daughter

The movie [***The Blackcoat's Daughter***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3286052/?ref_=nv_sr_6) was released earlier in UK with its original title **Febuary** pertaining to the month when the event takes place at the boarding school.

The movie also has an OST written for the movie itself by Elvis Perkins - Incantation ~ Outcantation - The Blackcoat's Daughter OST (2017) Audio.(Youtube video title)

My question: Why was the name "The Blackcoat's Daughter" given?

- Was it only to draw a connection with the OST track (which I believe in turn is actually based on the title itself)
- Is there any myth or legend regarding any "Blackcoat's Daughter" from which the movie got inspired?
- Does the "Blackcoat" here simply represent the character Father Brian who exorcises the spirit out of Kat towards the end?

I have gone through the [IMDB Trivia section](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3286052/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv), the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blackcoat%27s_Daughter) and one of Oz Perkin's interview but couldn't find any reference to this title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by the director **Osgood "Oz" Perkins**, son of *Psycho* star Anthony Perkins, [in an interview with AV Club](https://film.avclub.com/horror-is-a-trojan-horse-for-the-blackcoat-s-daughter-d-1798259716):

> **AVC:** There’s been a lot of interest in the title being changed from
>   *February* to *The Blackcoat’s Daughter*. Can you explain how all that
>   went down, and the thought process behind the new title?
>
> **OP:** For me, with the [original] title of *February*, I was going for the
>   idea that a time can also be a location. In other words, you can
>   re-visit a time of year, in the same way you can go back to a house
>   that you used to live in. A certain month or a certain season can
>   elicit a certain emotional response. That’s certainly true for anyone
>   who has a negative anniversary on their calendar—the approach of that
>   month brings the feeling of being very much back in another room. It’s
>   a time that stands outside the rest of the year. So that’s where the
>   title of *February* came from.
>
> **When the movie was bought by A24 to be distributed, I think they
>   wanted a title that indicated the genre a little more strongly.** I
>   didn’t accept the alternate titles they were putting forth, so I went
>   through [the film]. And **I had a lot of suggestions, but I sort of
>   landed on *The Blackcoat’s Daughter*. It’s a verse from this rhyme [for
>   which] my brother Elvis wrote the music, and we used it as an
>   incantation at the beginning and at the end of the movie: “Beetle
>   beetle, blackcoat’s daughter, what was in the holy water?”** I really
>   liked the word “daughter,” and Elvis and I decided that maybe the
>   backcoat’s daughter was a priest’s daughter. In any case, it worked
>   for a priest, it worked for the devil, it worked for a father, it had
>   the quality of a child raised by this strange black coat. It felt sexy
>   enough.

Comment: Nice find. Well played.

Comment: wow!! thanks a ton BCdotWEB!!.so it seems like a mixture of my first and last speculations. I missed this interview though. My bad.:)